# Summarizing statistics (mean, sd) in Stata, when there are three dichotomous explanatory variables

Tags: stata, summary

I am trying to create a table of summary statistics (mean, sd) for a DV when there are three dichotomous IV. Using the command `tab IV1 Iv2, sum (DV)` I can create a summary statistics table for only two IV variables, but not for three. However, I need the summary stats for the three IV and their interactions. Is there any way around? An alternative command? Thanks!

Comment: For some religious people, DV means "God willing". For many economists, IV means "instrumental variable". You mean dependent and independent variables, but neither abbreviation is universal across statistical science.

Answer (score 3):

You can make an interaction variable like this:

```
webuse nlswork
egen interaction = group(race nev_mar union), label
tab interaction, sum(ln_wage)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I use the same well-chosen sandbox as Dimitriy.

```
webuse nlswork, clear 
quietly statsby n=r(N) mean=r(mean)  sd=r(sd), by(race nev_mar union)  subsets clear: summarize ln_wage
egen nvars = rownonmiss(race nev_mar union )
sort nvars race nev_mar union 
format mean sd %4.3f 
l race-sd, sepby(nvars) noobs 

+-------------------------------------------------+  
|  race   nev_mar   union       n    mean      sd |
|-------------------------------------------------|
|     .         .       .   28534   1.675   0.478 |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| white         .       .   13590   1.796   0.464 |
| black         .       .    5426   1.647   0.458 |
| other         .       .     211   1.890   0.510 |
|     .         0       .   15509   1.758   0.466 |
|     .         1       .    3718   1.740   0.477 |
|     .         .       0   14720   1.702   0.466 |
|     .         .       1    4507   1.927   0.432 |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| white         0       .   11399   1.794   0.462 |
| white         1       .    2191   1.808   0.474 |
| white         .       0   10774   1.753   0.465 |
| white         .       1    2816   1.961   0.422 |
| black         0       .    3955   1.651   0.455 |
| black         1       .    1471   1.634   0.467 |
| black         .       0    3779   1.551   0.432 |
| black         .       1    1647   1.867   0.440 |
| other         0       .     155   1.893   0.553 |
| other         1       .      56   1.881   0.369 |
| other         .       0     167   1.865   0.510 |
| other         .       1      44   1.983   0.507 |
|     .         0       0   11936   1.707   0.464 |
|     .         0       1    3573   1.930   0.429 |
|     .         1       0    2784   1.682   0.474 |
|     .         1       1     934   1.914   0.444 |
|-------------------------------------------------|
| white         0       0    9071   1.751   0.462 |
| white         0       1    2328   1.961   0.423 |
| white         1       0    1703   1.766   0.479 |
| white         1       1     488   1.958   0.420 |
| black         0       0    2745   1.556   0.433 |
| black         0       1    1210   1.867   0.429 |
| black         1       0    1034   1.536   0.430 |
| black         1       1     437   1.866   0.469 |
| other         0       0     120   1.856   0.550 |
| other         0       1      35   2.020   0.553 |
| other         1       0      47   1.888   0.391 |
| other         1       1       9   1.842   0.235 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

So you get compactly all the three-way combinations, all the two-way, all the one-way and the overall summary. Moreover, this summary set is now the dataset in memory, so you can manipulate it further, export it, and so forth.